# Getting a "snapshot", instead of "custom image" when trying to create a custom image from a VM

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I am trying to create a custom image from a running VM. The process seemed to be successful
[image]

but the result shows as "snapshot". What I am doing wrong? Or maybe I need to somehow convert a snapshot into an image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After your snapshot is created you have to create disk, from that disk you will be able to create VM.

Follow these steps:

> Click on snapshot and from there click on **create disk**
> [As shown here in this ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGgwe.png)
> After the Disk has been created, go the Disks section click on the disk that you named while creating it from snapshot and click on **Create VM** [As shown here in this ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbJRc.png)
> and finish the required steps to create vm once it has been created you will be able to access it

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I actually did create the image successfully, I just looked in the wrong place for the results.